# Mocha: skip tests in nested describes

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js

I have some code below:

```
const assert = require('assert')

describe('server', function() {
  before(function() {
    // HACK: skip the tests in staging environment until we find to provide db in it
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {
      this.skip();
    }
  });

  it('list request', function() {
    assert.fail('fails wo db')
  })
  describe('detail requests', function() {
    it('some arguments', function() {
      assert.fail('fails wo db')
    })
  })
})
```

When I run `NODE_ENV='staging' npm test`:

```
> @ test /Users/kharandz/Projects/mocha-bug
> mocha



  server
    - list request
    detail requests
      1) some arguments


  0 passing (10ms)
  1 pending
  1 failing

  1) server detail requests some arguments:
     AssertionError: 'fails wo db' undefined undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/sample.spec.js:16:14)
```

But I expect that all the tests are skipped. So, the question:

- How to achieve the expected behavior without copying before-code in every describe?
- Is there any reason why it works like this?

Answer (score 3):

It appears it's not supported by Mocha, and it's considered a "feature".

See: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2683

Can be workaround by

```
before(function () {
  this.test.parent.pending = true;
  this.skip();
});
```

Comment: the issue is created by myself)

Comment: I've noticed, still I added above comment for others. (I came first here, and seeing no answer, started to search mocha tracker ;-)